# how to add background worker forfunction with "out" parameters in c#

Tags: c#

If i have a function with the "out" parameters like follows,

public void AddData(string s1 ,string s2 ,out string s3)

{

//some definition

}

Then How i add the background worker for this kind of method?

Comment: Why do you need out param here ? you can set the result in the e.Result of Completed event.

Comment: What does a `BackgroundWorker` have anything to do with the `out` parameter?

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. Please explain what you mean by "add the background worker". Use a detailed code example to show precisely what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
worker.DoWork += (s, e) => 
{ 
  string result; 
  AddData(s1, s2, out result);
  e.Result = result;
}
```

Comment: If i;m using like this, it throws the following Exception, "Can't use the out or ref parameter inside the anonymous method,lambda expression or query expression".

Comment: @AravindRaja: you are correct that this is not a solution. But please use correct terminology. The code never runs, so no exception could possible be thrown. Instead, you are seeing a _compiler error_ that is emitted when the code is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the backgroundworker

```
    BackgroundWorker bw;
```

then create the background worker and hook its events

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);

        //you can add ReportsProgress and RunWorkerCompleted events
    }
```

declare your method

```
    public void AddData(string s1, string s2, out string s3)
    {
        s3 = "big brown fox";
    }
```

in DoWork

```
    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
            string mystrign = "";
            AddData("", "", out mystrign);
            MessageBox.Show(mystrign);
    }
```

now run the background worker

```
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```